# Trackers don't line up with tracking

Tags: 3d-view, camera, tracking

i'm making a vfx project in blender and with a solve error of only 0.28px the trackers don't line up with the tracking dots in the viewport.
here's an example-

[image: glaze at the viewport, after I set up the scene and assigned origin and floor and an axis, the trackers don't line up with tracking dots.]